# Regular expression to get Valid HTTP Characters

Tags: java, regex, http, http-headers

As per [RFC 1738][1]

[1]: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt there are unsafe characters in http headers, query parameters and path parameters which should be filtered out. I am trying to get a regular expression for all the characters that can be allowed or whitelisted

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Character Classes" in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Excerpt:

```
Character classes
[abc]   a, b, or c (simple class)
[^abc]  Any character except a, b, or c (negation)
[a-zA-Z]    a through z or A through Z, inclusive (range)
[a-d[m-p]]  a through d, or m through p: [a-dm-p] (union)
[a-z&&[def]]    d, e, or f (intersection)
[a-z&&[^bc]]    a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction)
```